# Code failing to validate SAML Response on digest

Tags: java, validation, saml, xml-dsig

## Update

I have figured out why the reference validation is failing. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what to do about it.

When parsing the "sigString" String variable into the "doc" Document variable, the LINEFEED characters are being converted into SPACE characters. I have confirmed this by doing a manual generation of the digest value and comparing it to the value that is computed by the Java code.

Does anybody know how to preserve the LINEFEED characters when parsing an XML string into a org.w3c.dom.Document variable?

---

## Original Post

I am attempting to write some java code to verify the XML digital signature of a SAML response.  I have verified the SAML response with other tools, so I know it is valid (excluding timing issues, not a factor to the digital signature).  Below is the code I have used that I believe should be able to do this validation as well as the signature I am trying to validate.

When I run the code, I get the following output

```
Signature 0:
..Signature failed core validation
....signature validation status: true
....ref[0, #id14167335278088961501144300] validation status: false

Signature 1:
..Signature passed core validation
....signature validation status: true
....ref[0, #id141673352781342501524143644] validation status: true
```

I have no idea why the digest for reference `id14167335278088961501144300` is not validating.  Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

*Note: I am loading the XSD from a URL in this example so I don't have to include 4 XSD files in my question.  However, because of this, the program can take a minute to run.  I know this slowdown can be eliminated with local XSD files, it just is not feasible to do that way with the posted code*

## XMLDSigVerifier.java:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMValidateContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.test.dsig.X509KeySelector;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLDSigVerifier {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, KeyStoreException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        //Get XML as a string, will be parameter in final version
        String sigString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/signature.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(sigString));

        //Get X509Certificate as a string, will be parameter in final version
        String samlCertString= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        X509Certificate samlCert;

        samlCert = parseCertificate(samlCertString);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("a", samlCert);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
//      File xsd = new File("src/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd");
//      Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsd);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new URL("http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd"));
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setSchema(schema);
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);

        NodeList signatureNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
        Node signatureNode;

        for (int sigIndex = 0; sigIndex < signatureNodeList.getLength(); sigIndex++) {
            signatureNode = signatureNodeList.item(sigIndex);

            if (sigIndex > 0) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("Signature " + sigIndex + ":");

            DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new X509KeySelector(ks), signatureNode);
            valContext.setProperty("javax.xml.crypto.dsig.cacheReference", Boolean.TRUE);

            XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
            XMLSignature signature = factory.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
            boolean coreValidity = signature.validate(valContext);

            //Check Validity
            if (coreValidity == false) {
                System.err.println("..Signature failed core validation");
                try {
                    //Sleep because of eclipse bug
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("..Signature passed core validation");
            } 

            //Check validity Parts
            //Validity Part 1: Check Signature Validation
            boolean sv = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(valContext);
            System.out.println("....signature validation status: " + sv);

            //Validity Part 2: Check References         
            Iterator<?> i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().iterator();
            for (int j = 0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
                Reference ref = (Reference) i.next();
                boolean refValid = ref.validate(valContext);
                System.out.println("....ref[" + j + ", " + ref.getURI() + "] validation status: " + refValid);
            }
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate parseCertificate(String certStr) throws CertificateException{
        java.util.Base64.Decoder dec = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();   
        String beginCert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
        String endCert = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
        byte [] decoded = dec.decode(
                certStr
                    .replaceAll(beginCert, "")
                    .replaceAll(endCert, "")
        );

        return (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
    }
}
```

## signature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://apps.surdellpartners.com/ords/kohls_wmj/workamajig/okta/acs/" ID="id14167335278088961501144300" IssueInstant="2017-01-27T18:21:53.483Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">http://www.okta.com/exk8y9z9v7FSYL34Y0h7</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id14167335278088961501144300"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>7HyoOBjYlu8fbvSMNIY4O0fc6BhrkAUaPrF9EYWq/wE=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>dOhPiIwGvLJac40XW4x5Xn5soIzImitr/HAxRojDwSbAbfRp9t/VuRFT2Rat5oGgV3tWHedN7VBNpSGzBfZsYMBB/s/WYH0EQisTuS8iGXpNzxUIb0e9zbSFZIDiy3M1Zi8afC/EPrbP/SlBnXR0UXuyJW8KbfMZq9suw2GghVLI03q8FjLdFGBb4VZ2X5hqr4+qSpnS1+8RB+0bqtADKjYt9DP7vuhxz1jBI5o29OQOFZjW2K2g9Qr7ANUzaNFnIW50Lo4BH/qt60tA/UuZUNxwY+z3MM5ARb4zQYa8O/yQOPfvcKb0Ff9V4hHjlNtiZoZCOWq/2+ir9t7wxPwvNg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDpDCCAoygAwIBAgIGAVjUwdcaMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGSMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG
A1UECAwKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzENMAsGA1UECgwET2t0YTEU
MBIGA1UECwwLU1NPUHJvdmlkZXIxEzARBgNVBAMMCmRldi02NjI2ODExHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEW
DWluZm9Ab2t0YS5jb20wHhcNMTYxMjA2MTUyOTIzWhcNMjYxMjA2MTUzMDIzWjCBkjELMAkGA1UE
BhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xDTALBgNV
BAoMBE9rdGExFDASBgNVBAsMC1NTT1Byb3ZpZGVyMRMwEQYDVQQDDApkZXYtNjYyNjgxMRwwGgYJ
KoZIhvcNAQkBFg1pbmZvQG9rdGEuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
vLvIOJ11216IzuqZAbTiAoJy6WYxWuGXeUn4rpYkXLGOO0OoDahzhyquCQgLQC8mGlxCAq8gETQc
dL+SX7lOlavHcNYiaYUD9IipMV0Kqt8TgfLO8UuYLb2jNNaQp+0tbcYv4SHpC4nXTndlo2nk3cJV
ELvXYfvjqKzDvtMwACy37Vc01GZbFQXhSEfBt9J2aQzLPFzH/RxKeOjzKW0kxWgYpfP0NZPtwkHr
sdZaqpaR+039v5bckVSQvs0ZMz1Ionv+keWzM6YpQg7sF/OsvN05u0tkrGYDq1BoM9yH1h11bXrV
hLvdOjo4bSVjeiAZ2LNOTurGO4JfH+CqT15c5wIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQC8jLBo
AM35/6pwtUJ86BhYKvtjB6t3k+5uFRUx8rBWYL5atirRPF73W4f6AIkIp36zkS0os0RHuFK0bG2F
PnjQj+FpErd8zji8PVFQ2LZ0WPNLYP7g7BWxAoNct2q0Iw3TACY6h722Cq6WS9ZP4O2iv3kkpo4A
7JZvuf4yGGY2nVfx5nLZAmcEA9bZmHhcgmPLs2FBYpLYPs/5P4nd2HeiTJW+F6M75g9E4wG+sf3q
2zqzh+AmV5kHffWnGx2MPdUmyFPU80zcDzEpodVU73YUxJIJScwjjXzytuQSB2FcM0TMqwYUq2qG
VAPhBw4nnAxeScbMyMbFVDrNyMeejDhq</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></saml2p:Status><saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="id141673352781342501524143644" IssueInstant="2017-01-27T18:21:53.483Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://www.okta.com/exk8y9z9v7FSYL34Y0h7</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id141673352781342501524143644"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>EhCfdS3vR7BT/a3ITrTVoSazAvQbiKlAeMpaOJv9wEs=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>GSbmKitI52o4eZm94ivVGfXpLHiiTCvvvy6uEfO+37Z95kK8hU3OniWeZW01NlqxrDqC1eZkrPBEqMWPW0+K5oeiHkaedCpVafn1mZLNYQNKJetKhYNczK7tiCZn9P66JOXfPfALOlsC0nVvL10m5CmLjQ/m1VW8BE5N58OsNO8mCDycupvFMp/Q0tvvAf5DUkY2A3Y6Chx/i4cAYpJKGjBppNNpdzVYNlvKYvImk6d25Gx+1J7H7+0uYheYkEPFLd+7Kr8rUpqV2t33iEyILc3LXabQmmNiNHxaGD9gmccsGNTddm3Q1Uso2SXm2lw6/FqdozbKFxs6qJKrm9VmLQ==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDpDCCAoygAwIBAgIGAVjUwdcaMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGSMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2:Subject xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">jason.lyle88@gmail.com</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-27T18:26:53.483Z" Recipient="https://apps.surdellpartners.com/ords/kohls_wmj/workamajig/okta/acs/"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2017-01-27T18:16:53.483Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-27T18:26:53.483Z" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>http://localhost:8081/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/metadata</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-01-27T18:21:53.483Z" SessionIndex="id1485541313483.890561695" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><saml2:Attribute Name="firstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Jason</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute><saml2:Attribute Name="lastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Lyle</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion></saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: By any chance did you find a resolution to this? Looks like I'm having the same issue here using Okta...